# _stprintf_s treats "10" as "1"

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to pass a number into an array of BYTES - but to treat the number as an array of chars.
Here's my code:

```
for(int i=1;i<=totalFiles;i++)
{
    BYTE* input = new BYTE[sizeof(DWORD) * sizeof(TCHAR)];
    _stprintf_s((TCHAR*)input, sizeof(DWORD) * sizeof(TCHAR), _T("%d"), i);

    QueueToThreadPool(input);
}
```

For some reason when i=10 or i=11 (etc...) input only gets the value of "1" instead the value of i.
Why is that?

Comment: Are you trying to get the string representation of the number or the actual bytes that represent it in memory? If it's the string representation you want, then using `sizeof(DWORD)` doesn't really make sense (that would limit the values to 999).

Comment: You also have a buffer overflow since you are passing a byte count instead of a character count.

Comment: 1) Why allocate `sizeof(DWORD)` tchars when what you really need is the length of the string representation of an integer? If i is 12345, `sizeof(DWORD)` isn't large enough to hold the result. 2) The terminating zero will take up space too; allow for it by adding 1. 3) What they said; Unicode, 16 bits TCHARS, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that your program is built as a UNICODE program but whatever is using the string is treating it as a plain ASCII string.  So the most significant byte of the first UNICODE char (which is zero) is seen as the end of the string.